# Canvas and JavaScript - Flowing word from right to left while waiting for keypress input

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm new and I am trying to write my first program. In this snippet I try to flow a word from right to left and on the left move a bar to the right and when they collide a life will be taken. I also have a keypress event that strips the word of its corresponding character. The problem is that the animation goes too fast. There is no time to listen for input and give score. I have tried with setTimeout and SetInterval but they dont work. Thanks a bunch!

```js
let positionBar = 10;
let positionWord = 600;
let positionWordHeight = 90;
const word = "Word";
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function clrScr() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.trunc(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

while (positionBar < 600 && positionBar < positionWord) {
  clrScr();
  positionBar += 0.01;
  positionWord -= 0.07;

  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(positionBar, 10, 10, 200, "black");
  context.fill();

  context.font = "30px Arial";
  context.fillText(word, positionWord, positionWordHeight);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="800"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi thank you! I tried setInterval before and it doesnt work, and now i tried requestanimationfram() like this below and it still doesnt work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a callback like [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) or [`requestanimationframe()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to draw each frame sequentially. Here's a simple example that only modifies your code slightly. You should research the topic to understand more fully.

```js
let positionBar = 10;
let positionWord = 600;
let positionWordHeight = 90;
const word = "Word";
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function clrScr() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.trunc(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function draw(elapsed)
{
  if (positionBar < 600 && positionBar < positionWord) {
    clrScr();
    positionBar += 0.01;
    positionWord -= 0.07;

    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(positionBar, 10, 10, 200, "black");
    context.fill();

    context.font = "30px Arial";
    context.fillText(word, positionWord, positionWordHeight);

    // Call again for next frame
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
}

// Start animation
window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="800"></canvas>
```